# Pictorial "riddle"

Tags: riddle, visual, rebus

Look at the ordered images below and determine the phrase that they collectively represent:

[image]

Hint: It's a "thing"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's

> The S&P 500 stock index.
>  Salt & Pepper -> S&P
>  5
>  Hun (as in Attila)
>  Dread(locks)

Comment: D$%# that was quick.

Comment: Looks more like P&S than S&P!